# return values for Ruby setter

Tags: ruby

I read that `attr_writer :age` is short hand for this:

```
def age=(value)
  @age = value
end
```

So I created a class with a function like this:

```
    def age=(value)
        if @age == -1
            @age = value
            return true
        end

        return false
    end
```

Then I wanted to call it like this in another place:

```
rv = Foo.age(1)
# do stuff with rv
```

But I get an error:

```
  ArgumentError:
       wrong number of arguments (given 1, expected 0)
```

Anyway, I can do something like `Foo.age = 1` but that doesn't give me control over the return value. What is the proper idiomatic Ruby here?

Comment: I think the `=` method is somehow forced to return the val passed into it (e.g. 1), my question is why are you trying to do this? Or just curiosity?

Comment: Suppose the age function did a bunch of complicated networking that was non-deterministic, then I'd want to know if it succeeded or not in the calling function.

Comment: That error message doesn't make sense. You should get a `NameError` "undefined method `age`", not an `ArgumentError`, since you have only defined a method named `age=`, and no method named `age`. There must be something else going on that you are not showing us.

Comment: @maxpleaner: The method can have any return value it wants, it is not forced to return anything. However, assignment expressions evaluate to the value of the right-hand side, so the only way to observe the return value is to not use an assignment expression.

Comment: Thank you @JörgWMittag that's interesting .. my mistake

Answer (score 0):

how about a wrapper method that do 2 steps: first it'll try to set value `age=` then validate that `age == new_value` and return, so that you could know that the setter is success or not.

```rb
class Foo
 def age=(val)
  # do a bunch of complicated networking that was non-deterministic
  # return true/false
 end
 
 def set_age(val)
   self.age = val
   @age == val
 end
end

foo = Foo.new
result = foo.set_age(1)
```

you could also replace true/false by raising an error, then you could wrap setter into a begin-end block

```
class Foo
  def age=(val)
   # do a bunch of complicated networking that was non-deterministic
   raise RuntimeError
  end
end

result = begin
 foo.age = 1
 true
rescue => e
 false
end
```